R be a semiprime ring, not right singular, and with finitely uniform dimension to the right
if R is a semiprime ring, not right singular, and with finitely uniform dimension to the right. how can I Show that if I is a non-zero right ideal of R, then there exists an element y ∈ I such that
I ∩  $ran_R(y)$ = {0}.

Hi: i don't think the participants of mathoverflow like the splitting of questions between the title and post body any more than math.se users do.  You can easily edit it to make the post body have complete context.

And I'm guessing "ranR(Y)" means "the right annihilator of y in R?"  it can be typeset more clearly as $r.ann(y)$ or $r.ann_R(y)$ if you like.

Thank you  for your clarification .do you have any suggestion how to solve this ?

Nothing jumps out at me, no. Maybe you should also mention the source of the problem.
